# Python datetime.today() Showing different time in different python programms

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-datetime

I am having 2 different python file, `views.py` in django and a `test.py` .I use `test.py` to write a specific function and check if iam getting desired output,and if yes, i will copy that code to `views.py` in my django project.
Today i was writting a function to calculate time intervals of 15 mins and populate a list.
When i was trying to do `print('Today: ',datetime.today())` in `test.py` it was giving the correct output and a different output in `views.py`

Here's the output in both

`test.py`:  `Today:  2022-01-13 20:28:45.613094`

`views.py`: `Today:  2022-01-13 14:58:25.850835`

Note:In my views.py there are other function which uses datetime libraries but iam sure that they are not interfering with each other

Here's the Code i use to generate a list of time with interval of 15 mins:

```
def datetime_range(start, end, delta):
  current = start
  while current <= end:
    yield current
    current += delta

def create():
  print('Today: ',datetime.today())  #This is where the problem occurs!
  a=datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%I:%M')
  h=a[0:2]


  dts = [dt.strftime('%I:%M') for dt in 
     datetime_range(datetime(2022, 1, 1,int(h)), datetime(2022, 1, 1,9), 
     timedelta(minutes=15))]

 new=[]
 for d in dts:
    if datetime.strptime(d,'%I:%M') > datetime.strptime(a,'%I:%M'):
          new.append(d)


 return new
```

Comment: looks like your Django app is set to use UTC and the machine you run the test on is set to UTC+5:30

Comment: @MrFuppes  You are right,my django timezone was set to utc,by changing that, the problem was solved

Comment: Python's concept of naive datetime can be quite confusing at times like these.

Answer (score 3):

Your offset of 5 and a half hours between the two results indicates you are probably located in India, and you found an issue with timezones. Try using `datetime.utcnow()` instead, and continue from there.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem,But as suggested by @MrFuppes,it was a problem with django configuration